# Handle session timeout loss of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In a module I wrote I store in the session the items the user added to his cart.
How would you handle this situation: The user adds a new item to his cart after the session timedout?
I can redirect to the homepage but then I'm causing the redirect to happen even when the session wasn't in use. like when the user isn't logged in, or his cart was empty.

How do you handle session timeout in your applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I might not use the built in ASP.NET Session provider.  Instead you could set a persistent cookie for the customer's shopping cart session with an encrypted ID that maps to a session stored in the database, which stores the contents of the cart.

This way, you don't need to worry about timeouts, the session will continue for the lifetime of the cookie.

(If you really need to use ASP.NET Session, maybe you've already got code that uses it, then you could set the timeout to a very large number and configure the [Session state provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) to use SQL Server.)

Comment: The cart can have up to 3500+ items. Do you still think cookie is a good idea? store all that data for each partial buy? it's too much work to handle the database for temporary data -trigger and stuff.

Comment: **"configure the Session state provider to use SQL Server"** how? what does it  do? thanks.

Comment: Only the encrypted ID is stored in the cookie (cookies should be used to store more than about 4KB). This is used to reference session data stored in the database.

Comment: Added link to configuring different Session state modes.

Answer (score 1):

Your page can have a javascript timer running and when the time runs out the page is redirected to another page, say login, with query string parameters as flags. When the Login screen is called with x flag, then the shopping cart is saved to the database for safe keeping. The key is to have the timeout be shorter than the session timeout.

**ADDED:**

Javascript on each page:

```
<body onload="PageLoad();">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function PageLoad() 
    {
        var t = setTimeout("ExceuteTimeOutTransfer()", 15000);
    }

    function ExceuteTimeOutTransfer() 
    {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost/webplaying/Login.aspx?timeout=Y";
    }
</script>
```

Code Behind on Login Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["timeout"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["timeout"].ToUpper() == "Y")
        {
            SaveCart();
        }
    }
}

private void SaveCart()
{
    lblResult.Text = "Cart Saved";
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach! can you please share a piece of code with us how to make this magic happen? and what if the user left the page open for an hour and he didn't see the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to store the cart in a cookie.